# "Cannot assign value of type freddy '[JSON]' to type '[NSString]'

Tags: ios, json, swift, nsarray

I am developing a swift 5 project using Freddy FrameWork (for parsing). I have a requirement like when user search for the zipcode in autocomplete it will display the zipcodes from Array. But my code is getting crash.I am retrieving the zipcode from "JSON"(using Freddy). using the below code

```
struct FreddyJson: JSONDecodable {
       let zipCodes: [JSON]
}  

 init(json: JSON) throws {
    do{
          let zipCodes = try? json.getArray(at: "WarningConfigurationUS", "ZipCode")
            self.zipCodes = zipCodes!
            }catch{
            print(error)
        }  
    }
```

After that I am calling this in ViewController.swift file like as below

```
func FreddyDataParsing()
  {
      let data = DataService.shared.readCustomizerMappingJson()
      guard let freddy = try? FreddyJson(json: data) else {return}

    self.autoCompletionPossibilities = freddy.zipCodes  // I am getting an error  "Cannot assign value of type '[JSON]' to type '[NSString]'"
  }
```

The below code is fo getting the autosearch result

```
 func getAutocompleteSuggestions(userText: String) -> [String]{
           var possibleMatches: [String] = []
           for item in autoCompletionPossibilities { //2
               let myString:NSString! = item as NSString.  //Here also I am getting the same error
               let substringRange :NSRange! = myString.range(of: userText)

               if (substringRange.location == 0)
               {
                   possibleMatches.append(item as String)
               }
           }
           return possibleMatches
       }
```

Can anyone help me to resolve the above issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: autoCompletionPossibilities what is ? like it's [NSString] or [Json]

Comment: Thank you. Got the solution.

Comment: How @ios? like what is the issue here.

Comment: let zipCodes = try? json.getArray(at: "WarningConfigurationUS", "ZipCode") instead of this i should use   let zipCodes = try? json.getArray(at: "WarningConfigurationUS", "ZipCode").compactMap({ try? $0.getString() }) which will store it as a String.